# Axios network error (Invalid imageTag) when querying a Flask resource from React Native iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, flask, axios, expo

I have a Flask app set up with a few endpoints. These endpoints work fine when accessed from postman or a browser.

I also have a React Native app set up (using an Expo template), in which I try to query this resource from iOS:

```
const testApiCall = async (): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    const url = `${baseUrl}/users`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data.toString();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.request)
    console.log(" a " + error.request?._response);
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

`baseUrl` is the full IP, not just `localhost`.

The `/users` endpoint returns json of the app's users. However, when calling this, I get the following output:

```
a Invalid imageTag: 192.168.1.191:80/users
[AxiosError: Network Error]
```

(excluding the `error.request` since it's long and probably doesn't provide any additional context - will edit this post if it would be useful!)

I can't find any reason for the "invalid imageTag" error. Intermittently, the flask app will get logs including a 404 request for the favicon:

```
[06/May/2022 21:55:05] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[06/May/2022 21:55:05] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[06/May/2022 21:56:15] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[06/May/2022 21:56:16] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I even tried to make an endpoint in the flask app to return a generic .ico file when requesting `/favicon.ico` but behavior didn't change. Now, I stopped getting any kind of request on my flask app when using my React Native app. I still get logs when accessing the endpoints from postman, though.

I also used `flask_cors`:

`CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})`

This one has been a real head-scratcher for me and I'm having trouble finding any similar issues, so I'd really appreciate any help! Happy to provide additional context that could be useful, too.

A request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 worked without an issue. Tried with http:// and that worked too.

Added this to `app.json` but it didn't help:

```
"ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSAppTransportSecurity" : {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true,
          "NSAllowsLocalNetworking": true
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my logic for getting the `baseUrl` excluded the `http://`. Prepending the baseUrl with `'http://'` solved the issue. It's always something obvious that I miss!